# Powershell: Debug function to print out failed function name (from a module)

Tags: powershell, debugging

Hi,
I wrote a nice debug function that provides the name of function from which it's called. The code is:

```powershell
Function Write-Log {
  $callerName = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value.MyCommand.Name

  $stamp = (Get-Date).toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
  $line = "$stamp [$level`]: $callerName $Message"

  Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor $color
}
```

Works great when called from inside .ps1 script; however I started refactoring code so that some functions are moved to a .psm1 module - and this is where the function fails. Instead of printing the function name, it only provides the name of module.

How can I fix this function so that it only shows the function name, or scope & function name?

Comment: From your module, try using `$callerName = "{0} - {1}:" -f (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Location, (Get-PSCallStack)[1].FunctionName`.  Side note: `$Message`, `$color` and `$level` are undefined in your Write-Log Function.  Might be best to supply them as optional params with sane default values.

Comment: Thanks for help - they are actually defined, I only omitted Params section for clarity, as not related to actual question. And thanks, what you suggested works exactly as I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [leeharvey1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11609403/leeharvey1). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

From your module, you can try using `$callerName = "{0} - {1}:" -f (Get-PSCallStack)[1].Location, (Get-PSCallStack)[1].FunctionName`.